# Piping between Python and Ruby

Tags: python, ruby, python-3.x, pipe

I am writing a code which can send data between a Python and a Ruby script using a "pipeline" but can not get it to work. Any recommendations or alternative ways?

I have written simple scripts to get it working and build upon them. The objective is to integrate the "pipeline" functionality in a project. In the project, the Python script is to send a .txt file to the Ruby script, which will extract parameter values and store them in respective arrays. I then want to send the arrays back to the Python script.

The simple scripts i have made so far are inspired by https://www.decalage.info/python/ruby_bridge. When running, it continues without stopping and does not produce any results. The goal is to send the integer 6 to the Ruby script where 5 is added, and send the sum back to the Python script. When aborting with ctrl + c, the following is written:

```
File "./com_ruby.py", line 33, in <module>
    sss = slave.stdout.readline().rstrip()
```

My Python script:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

print('launching slave process...')
slave = Popen(['ruby', 'provar.rb'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)

while True:

    num = bytes([6])
    slave.stdin.write(num)
    # result will be a list of lines:
    result = []
    # read slave output line by line, until we reach "[end]"
    while True:
        # check if slave has terminated:
        if slave.poll() is not None:
            print('slave has terminated.')
            exit()
        # read one line, remove newline chars and trailing spaces:
        sss = slave.stdout.readline().rstrip()
        print('line: ', sss)
        if sss == '[end]':
            break
        result.append(sss)
    print('result:')
    print('\n'.join(result))
```

My Ruby script:

```
while cmd = STDIN.gets

    cmd.chop!

    cmd = cmd + 5

    cmd.to_s
    print eval(cmd),"\n"
    # append [end] so that master knows it's the last line:
    print "[end]\n"
    # flush stdout to avoid buffering issues:
    STDOUT.flush

end
```

Is there any better yet simple way to do the "piping" of data between the two scripts?

Comment: Have you considered simply using a predictable file path to store data, and have python and ruby both read from and write to the same data file?

Comment: One thing that could be stalling is not flushing stdout when you write to it.